# Replacing en-dash for hyphen in the index (makeindex)

Tags: makeindex

I need to make a change in the index (not contents) of my book: I need to change the en-dash ("long" dash) for the hyphen ("short" dash) when an entry of the index covers a group of pages (I mean, from page A to page B).  What I have is this 
[image]

and I need to replace that dashes (long dashes) for hyphens (short dashes).

How can I do it?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: this is my preamble

```
\documentclass[reqno,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{infwarerr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx,psfrag,float}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelsep=quad]{caption}%Configura el caption de las figuras
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}%Paquete para crear listas (enumerate, itemize) personalizadas
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}%"titles" permite cambiar tocloft con los comandos latex estándar para los títulos
\usepackage{natbib}%Paquete para citaciones
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{tasks}%Paquete para hacer listas enumeradas horizontalmente
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeindex%[name=Índice analítico,columns=2]
%\makeindex[columns=2]
.
.
.
\begin{document}
.
.
.
\include{Index}
\printindex
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I tried to use the **imakeidx** package but I didn't do it.

Comment: Typographically, this is heresy! B;t.w. the *long* dash is the `emdash`, not the endash.

Comment: Ok, Bernard.  I'm sorry for my mistake.  I need to change that "long" dash for the "short" dash.  How can I do it?

Comment: You should post a minimal working example. In particular which tools do you use for your index? Makeindex, xindy? Which packages?

Comment: having both `\include{Index}` and `\printindex` would duplicate the index, assuming that the file named `Index.tex` is present.  but it wouldn't be created by `imakeidx`.  what `imakeidx` does create is an `.idx` file, which is then sent through the `makeindex` program to create an `.ind` file, which is read in directly with the `\printindex` command.  the `--` is inserted into the page spans by the makeindex program.  i believe this can be modified by an `.ist` file, but you haven't provided any real data that can be used to experiment.

Comment: Dear Barbara.  What kind of data could I give you for experimenting?  I mean, if the index is made of the references that I put in the whole book (each chapter in a different .tex file), how could provide to you something that you can use for experimenting?  I'm asking for a way to print the hyphen instead of em-dash in the index.  How could I do it with an .ist file and how do I create that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an index style file.  This usually has the extension `.ist`.  There you can set the range delimiter with `delim_r`.  For simpler processing I use `imakeidx`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.ist}
delim_r "-"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s \jobname.ist]

\begin{document}

Hello World!\index{Foo}\newpage
Hello World!\index{Foo}\newpage
Hello World!\index{Foo}\newpage
Hello World!\index{Foo}\newpage

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Henry.  I did what you suggested and I got an error message: '! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.468 \makeindex[
program=makeindex,name=Índice analítico,options=-s Algebr...
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.'  I don't understand why.

Comment: @Fabio Did this happen with the exact example I posted? (it doesn't look like it)  If you have a follow-up question, just make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and ask a new question.

Comment: No, it doesn't happend with your example.  What I mean is that I included the options for **\makeindex** and I got the error message.   If I don't use the options for **\makeindex** the error message doesn't appear.  In both cases I loaded the **imakeidx** package.  I don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: Hi, Henry.  Finally I could solve the problem.  The problem was that I put the option **name=whatever**.  When I erased it, the code worked perfectly!!!! Thanks for your help.